# In Android is it possible to continuously show status bar notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-audiorecord

In my app, I have to continuously show status bar notification after some event is triggered. The status bar must glow in red rather than in default background. During that period,I am responsible for recording sound i.e. it is just like recorder but the instead of running in Activity, it will run on Service and the user is notified by blinking status bar in red. The user at any time can go the status bar and stop the recording.And the recording can carry on even when lockscreen is on.
So is it possible to achieve this in Android and if possible could you give us some logic for this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground), which lets you post an ongoing notification. There's no API for changing the color of the entire status bar. You can certainly color your icons, and on JellyBean and later you may be able to change the color of the notification itself using `RemoteViews` -- that's talked about [in this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification).

Comment: Ok I will look upon it and see whether,it makes me able to record audio while on lockscreen as well. Thanks for the head start